# accessing an html variable from typescript

Tags: html, typescript, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, ngfor

Please I need help with accessing an HTML variable from typescript, (in this case, Prod.firstname) in this project.
Prod.firstname is from my firestore data collection.
I've been able to display it on HTML but I want to access it in my typescript file so I can use it anywhere within the typescript. but I don't know how to go about it.
I would really appreciate help from any one thanks.Im new in programming.
here is my html code:

```
 <ion-card>
     <ion-card-header>
       <ion-card-title>
         First Name:
       </ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
     <ion-card-content>
       <div *ngFor="let prod  of prodobs| async">
         <p>{{prod.firstname}}</p>
       </div>
     </ion-card-content>
   </ion-card>
```

Comment: Can you share what your typescript file currently looks like? There has to be a place where this data is being set/fetched.

Comment: var prodobs = this.biocollection.doc(this.firstnameholder +""+ 
                    this.lastnameholder+""+this.phonenumberholder).set({
                              firstname: this.firstnameholder, lastname:this.lastnameholder, 
               dateofbirth: 
                     this.datetofbirthholder, phonenumber: this.phonenumberholder,
               };

Comment: Thanks a lot@ paintotpi. I had  created a set of data in firestore from another page  lets say page A prior to this current page(Page B), afterwards I displayed some of the data(prod.firstname) earlier created in firestore from page A on the html of the page I shared above(Page B),so what i intend doing now is to access the data that is displayed on the HTML of page B in the typescript of  page B. the code shared above is the typescript code for Page A where I originally created a firestore data: